# redireccionar Por htaccess con querys

Tags: php, sql, .htaccess

Actualmente tengo este tipo de URL y funciona bien:
    www.example.com/flower

La ruta completa del ejemplo es:

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower
```

Pero anteriormente la ruta se conformaba a traves de la IP en lugar de la CARPETA:

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?IP=202
```

Lo que necesito lograr es que cuando escriban la URL actual:

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower
```

O la URL anterior:

```
www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?IP=202
```

Me diriga a la URL definitiva:

```
www.example.com/flower
```

Actualmente en mi archivo .htaccess dice:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/indexmodelo\.php\?carpeta=([0-9a-zA-Z_\-&=]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_\-&=]+)$ /indexmodelo.php?carpeta=$1 [L]
```

Y no logro encontrar la forma de solucionarlo. GRACIAS!

Comment: Si necesitas redirigir el usuario a otra pagina normalmente utilizas `header("Location:lo_que_fuera.php")`en PHP o `window.location = 'http://www.example.com/lo_que_fuera.php';` en JavaScript. El .htaccess se utiliza para que el usuario pueda escribir `www.example.com/flower` para abrir `www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower` Si el usuario escribe `www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower` este sigue siendo un url válido.

Comment: Es que quiero que cuando escriban la URL:
    www.example.com/flower
muestre el contenido y quede esta URL como definitiva... ya que es una URL mas fácil de recordar que las otras.

Para ello, logré a traves del .htaccess que cuando escriben:
    www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?carpeta=flower

muestre www.example.com/flower

Pero no sé como lograr que cuando escriban la url vieja y ya indexada por Google:
    www.example.com/indexmodelo.php?ID=202

muestre la URL "linda y abreviada: www.example.com/flower

Answer (score 0):

En el código $1 representa una retroreferencia al primero grupo no pasivo o sea: el valor encontrado con la expresión regular entre paréntesis. En tu caso: $1 captura la "flor".

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^indexmodelo/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/$  indexmodelo.php?carpeta=$1

</ifModule>
```

Observación: ciertos editores de código, notablemente Dreamweaver, transforman .htaccess en otro tipo de fichero, y no funciona.

Comment: Pero eso no soluciona lo que quiero lograr. O al menos no me doy cuenta de como hacerlo... alguien me podría aclarar por favor? Gracias